# Does the combination of the Blinded and Deafened status effects make other creatures effectively hidden?

Tags: dnd-4e, conditions, stealth

If an item and or attack power in 4e gives a creature both the blinded and deafened status effects and the creature has no alternative senses (blind sight, tremor sight) is it mechanically accurate to treat all other creatures as hidden from the blinded and deafened creature?

Comment: This is a great question, because it showcases the emphasis 4e places on exact mechanical definitions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **blinded** condition doesn't do that.

> ### Blinded
>
> - The creature can’t see, which means its targets have total concealment against it.
> - The creature takes a -10 penalty to Perception checks.
> - The creature grants combat advantage.
> - The creature can’t flank.
>
> A blinded creature cannot have combat advantage against anyone. (RC229)

**People can hide anywhere from the blinded creature (since they have total concealment) but they're not automatically hidden.**
If they do hide, there's a -10 penalty to the Perception check to find them.

The only effect of the deafened condition is an additional -10 penalty to Perception (it is not total deafness) (RC230).

If the enemies don't hide, only a -5 to the blinded character's attack roll (for total concealment) applies.

For further reference, the [Rules of Hidden Club](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2739081) might be useful.